# How to best handle command that shows error in console but is returning exit 0

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm running into an issue with a Jenkins Pipeline. As part of our deploy process there is bash script that runs to validate the deployment files and deploy to an environment. There is a specific command at the end that uses a vendor's cli tool to deploy to our environment. If there is an error in this command, it appears to still be returning exit 0 and the build does not deploy but it is showing the job completed successfully in Jenkins. I thought about making an if statement as something like this to make the job fail if there is an error:

```
if $myCommand | grep -q '*** ERROR ***' &> /dev/null
then
    exit 1
fi
```

I do want the command to finish and deploy if an error is not found in this command. My question is would this work and/or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a fine way to do it, but your example is not grepping stderr, it is only grepping stdout. You'll want:

```
if $myCommand 2>&1 | grep ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could capture the output using Command substitution and print that message, otherwise, yeah just `grep -q`

```
output=$("$myCommand")
if [[ $output = *'*** ERROR ***'* ]]; then
   printf 'Uh oh, something went wrong!\n' >&2
   printf '%s\n' "$output" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

- Although this might work or any other answer on this post, still this is not a solution but just a band-aid, the proper solution is to fix the program/utility/command that does not properly give an exit status that you can act upon.